# How to properly set timestamp field seeder for a postgreSql database in Laravel 10.47?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, timestamp, laravel-8, laravel-seeding

I am using Laravel 10.47 and PostgreSql 14.2.

I an using the following piece of code in the migrations that creates the timestamps fields:

```
$table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
$table->softDeletes()->nullable()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
```

Inside the seed code I have the following scenarios:

1. I am not seeding `created_at`, `email_verified_at`, `updated_at` or `deleted_at`. In this case only `created_at` is seeded:
   [image]
2. When I seed `email_verified_at`, `updated_at` or `deleted_at` with `Carbon::now()->timestamp`

```
class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run(): void
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
        [
             'name' => 'Prof1',
             'middle_name' => 'Prof1',
             'last_name' => 'Prof1',
             'avatar' => 'prof1-Picture-S3',
             'role' => '0',
             'email' => 'Prof1@gmail.com',
             'password' => Hash::make('Prof1'),
             'remember_token' => 'some remember_token STRING',

             'email_verified_at' => Carbon::now()->timestamp,
             'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->timestamp,
             'deleted_at' => Carbon::now()->timestamp,
        ],
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Database\Seeders\UserTableSeeder ......................................................................................................... RUNNING  

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[22008]: Datetime field overflow: 7 ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "1711657211"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
CONTEXT:  unnamed portal parameter $2 = '...' (Connection: pgsql, SQL: insert into "users" ("avatar", "deleted_at", "email", "email_verified_at", "last_name", "middle_name", "name", "password", "remember_token", "role", "updated_at") values (prof1-Picture-S3, 1711657211, Prof1@gmail.com, 1711657211, Prof1, Prof1, Prof1, $2y$12$n9zt3JXLCCqP.N0LY2SVIeq1n.w3ifZQpTa2pWxo0lZKh7vzSAsl2, some remember_token STRING, 0, 1711657211), (prof2-Picture-S3, 1711657211, Prof2@gmail.com, 1711657211, Prof2, Prof2, Prof2, $2y$12$aPCTu8oup/PraiTE5cvQwOfUCOoThYhDF7gdyxTvuKGov0gFFPKD6, some remember_token STRING, 1, 1711657211), (Paci1-Picture-S3, 1711657212, Paci1@gmail.com, 1711657212, Paci1, Paci1, Paci1, $2y$12$pouVr40UAxCjtfQFd.srkeBo83Zm.ewYcE2iQeC9u7yue/OvoNte2, some remember_token STRING, 2, 1711657212))

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:829
    825▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    826▕                 );
    827▕             }
    828▕ 
  ➜ 829▕             throw new QueryException(
    830▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    831▕             );
    832▕         }
    833▕     }

      +7 vendor frames 

  8   database/seeders/UserTableSeeder.php:27
      Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert()
      +8 vendor frames 

  17  database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php:16
      Illuminate\Database\Seeder::call("Database\Seeders\UserTableSeeder")
```

I don't know if the problem is because I am using`Carbon` to seed a `PostgreSql` database.
Is there a way to seed that without error?

UPDATE

---

If I use `useCurrent()` inside the `Migration Class` instead of `useCurrentOnUpdate()` it works.

Scenario that works - using `useCurrent()`:

```
Inside the Migrations
$table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable()->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable()->useCurrent();
$table->softDeletes()->nullable()->useCurrent();

Inside seeder
Not calling or not seeding `email_verified_at`, `created_at`, `updated_at` and `deleted_at`.
```

Scenario that do not works - using `useCurrentOnUpdate()`:

```
Inside the Migrations
$table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
$table->softDeletes()->nullable()->useCurrentOnUpdate();

Inside seeder

'email_verified_at' => Carbon::now()->timestamp,
'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->timestamp,
'deleted_at' => Carbon::now()->timestamp

I get the error SQLSTATE[22008]: Datetime field overflow:
```

Comment: There is a method to do this already, you should not do it manually. `$table->timestamps();` Then just pass `Carbon::now()` as the column value.

Comment: Also just `$table->softDeletes();` and `$table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();` are sufficient. Values are specified on the queries.

Comment: @miken32, it seems that  `Carbon::now()` will not solve the issue since it is generating a type not expected to fill a timestamp field. `SQLSTATE[22008]: Datetime field overflow: 7 ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "1711721525"`

Comment: That still looks like a timestamp value. Are you properly casting in your model?

Comment: I am not using model for that.  Just added an UPDATE

Comment: Perhaps you should include the complete code causing the problem in your question

Comment: the code is there. Do you want the whole migration and the whole seeder? The only line causing the issue is those in the question.

Comment: There’s 3 elements of an array. No indication at all what you’re doing with it

Comment: ok I put it there. It is only the seeder class. Has no difference.